# Book with all-girl orphanage

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

This book is about a girl who grows up in an all girl orphanage. When the girls in the orphanage turn 18 they are sent away to live in the capital city where they believe they will live happy for the rest of their lives. The reality of this is when they graduate they get sent off to a different building (I think it was just across the lake from the orphanage) and they are forced to make babies for the rest of their lives to try and repopulate the world.

Right before the girl graduates she finds out that she is the king's daughter and actually goes to the capital city. She learns all these horrible secrets somehow about the girls (I don't remember how but I think she gets to see her friends that were taken to the building to have children.) She ends up running away and finds a man (The girls were always taught to be afraid and to run away because men will try to take advantage of them.) She hides away with the man while on the run from the king.

When the woman is with the man, who she later falls in love with, she is taken to his encampment to stay. The leader of the tribe/encampment is very nice to her around the other man but when she is there for awhile he tries to rape her. After she is saved from that situation the leader gives away her location to the king and she is captured and taken back to the city. Later on in the series she escapes again and somehow finds the man again. They travel to a location that is rumored to be a safe haven. The man gets injured along the way and when they finally make it there they find out that only women are allowed in the encampment.

The two lovers are forced to separate, the girl staying in the all female encampment to stay safe from the king. The man is eventually captured and used as a ploy to get the girl to come back to the capital city.

This book was written in English, I read it just a few years ago but don't know when it was published.

Answer (score 15):

I believe this is [***The Eve trilogy***](http://www.annacareybooks.com/books-eve) by Anna Carey.

> **Where do you go when nowhere is safe?**
>   Sixteen years after a deadly virus wiped out most of Earth’s population, the world is a perilous place. Eighteen-year-old Eve has never been beyond the heavily guarded perimeter of her school, where she and two hundred other orphaned girls have been promised a future as the teachers and artists of the New America. But the night before graduation, Eve learns the shocking truth about her school’s real purpose—and the horrifying fate that awaits her.
>
> Fleeing the only home she’s ever known, Eve sets off on a long, treacherous journey, searching for a place she can survive. Along the way she encounters Arden, her former rival from school, and Caleb, a rough, rebellious boy living in the wild. Separated from men her whole life, Eve has been taught to fear them, but Caleb slowly wins her trust . . . and her heart. He promises to protect her, but when soldiers begin hunting them, Eve must choose between true love and her life.

This is the excerpt of the first book, Eve. It is followed by Once and Rise.

Reference: [Anna Carey Books - Eve Trilogy](http://www.annacareybooks.com/books-eve)

Comment: That is it thank you so much!

Comment: @Emily If you get a chance, be sure to mark this answer as the correct one (it's the check mark symbol below the up and down voting arrows), so it marks the question as solved.